# How to Show AutoComplete Programmatically without entering a text

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

C# TextBox
`AutoCompleteCustomSource` has a `List<string>`,
`AutoCompleteMode` = `Suggest`.

I can see the List when I type a Letter.

How to show entire list without Typing a Letter Programmatically? This must be done while the User presses the Down Arrow Key in the TextBox.

Is there any Win32 API Available?

### My Solution

I refined a Better Solution.

Add a `ListBox` Control to the form and make it as `Visible = false`

```
int curSelIndex = -1;
```

The below given Code will be executed `Form_Load` Event.

```
txtEmpId.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(EmpIds.ToArray());
lstAutoComplete.Items.Clear();
lstAutoComplete.Items.AddRange(EmpIds.ToArray());
txtEmpId.KeyDown += (ks, ke) =>
{
    if (!(ke.KeyCode == Keys.Down || 
          ke.KeyCode == Keys.Up || 
          ke.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)) 
    { 
        lstAutoComplete.Visible = false; 
        return; 
    }
    ke.Handled = true;
    if (ke.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        if (lstAutoComplete.Visible)
        {
            var str = lstAutoComplete.SelectedItem + "";
            // Process the Selected Item and set to TextBox.
        }
    }
    if (!lstAutoComplete.Visible && txtEmpId.Focused)
    {
        var loc = txtEmpId.Location;
        loc.Y += txtEmpId.Height;
        lstAutoComplete.Location = loc;
        lstAutoComplete.Size = txtEmpId.Size;
        lstAutoComplete.Height = 100;
        lstAutoComplete.SelectedIndex = 0;
        curSelIndex = 0;
        lstAutoComplete.Visible = true;
    }
    else if(lstAutoComplete.Visible && txtEmpId.Focused)
    {
        if (ke.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            curSelIndex++;
            if (curSelIndex >= lstAutoComplete.Items.Count)
                curSelIndex = lstAutoComplete.Items.Count - 1;
            if (lstAutoComplete.Items.Count > 0)
                lstAutoComplete.SelectedIndex = curSelIndex;
        }
        else if (ke.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            curSelIndex--;
            if (curSelIndex < 0)
                curSelIndex = 0;
            if (lstAutoComplete.Items.Count > 0)
                lstAutoComplete.SelectedIndex = curSelIndex;
        }
    }
};
txtEmpId.Leave += (ls, le) => lstAutoComplete.Visible = false;
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185587/how-to-make-autocomplete-on-a-textbox-show-suggestions-when-empty

I guess it is not possible.

Answer (score 7):

I didn't find any API for your problem, so I just make a my own suggestion box by using `ListBox` to show when the Down Arrow Key is pressed, when you do other operation, it disappeares. I hope it is useful to you. code sample is bellow:

```
//string datasource
List<string> strList = null;
//suggestion listbox
ListBox sugBox = null;

public FrmTextSuggest()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //setting the textbox control
    strList = new List<string>()
    {
        "USA",
        "England",
        "China",
        "Japan",
        "Korea",
        "India",
        "France",
        "Canada"
    };
    var autoCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    autoCollection.AddRange(strList.ToArray());
    this.txtCountry.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autoCollection;
    this.txtCountry.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
    this.txtCountry.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;

    //register the Down Arrow Key event
    this.txtCountry.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(txtCountry_KeyDown);
}

void txtCountry_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    //show the your own suggestion box when pressing down arrow and the text box is empty
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down && txtCountry.Text.Trim().Equals(""))
    {
        sugBox = new ListBox();
        //define the box
        sugBox.Width = txtCountry.Width;
        Point p = txtCountry.Location;
        p.Y += txtCountry.Height;
        sugBox.Location = p;
        sugBox.Items.AddRange(strList.ToArray());
        //copy the value to the textbox when selected index changed.
        sugBox.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(sugBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
        //show box
        if (sugBox.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            sugBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
            this.Controls.Add(sugBox);
            sugBox.Focus();
        }
    }
    //remove and hide your own suggestion box when other operation
    else
    {
        if (sugBox != null && this.Controls.Contains(sugBox))
        {
            this.Controls.Remove(sugBox);
            sugBox.Dispose();
            sugBox = null;
        }
    }
}

void sugBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selText = this.sugBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selText))
    {
        this.txtCountry.Text = selText;
    }
}
```

here is my result of test:
[image: result picture1]

[image: result picture2]

Comment: What happens when User presses the Down key second Time??? the List box will be re initialized and shown??? Any ways thats the good idea but it have to be refined..

Comment: I added my solution based on your Idea.

Comment: Tricky but the best solution I found. Thank you @Scott