# FireTextChanged event of TextBox B when TextChanged event of TextBox A occurs

Tags: c#, winforms, events, textbox, event-handling

I have two `TextBoxes`: `A` and `B`.

I want `B` to imitate the behavior of `A`. So whenever `A`'s text changes, `B`'s text changes too.
This is doable by setting `B`'s text to `A`'s text whenever `A`'s text changes. But since `B` has an `AutoComplete` option, this `AutoComplete` will not work unless `B`'s TextChange event is fired, too.

So with each TextChange in `A`, I want to fire a TextChange in `B`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void TextChanged_A(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Do Anything
   //Then
    TextChanged_B(B,null);
}

void TextChanged_B(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do Anything
}
```

Comment: This looks like a good idea. But I don't know why my `B`'s AutoComplete options don't appear this way. They work when I directly type into `B`, but not when I type into `A`. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Pedram http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20920492/how-to-show-autocomplete-programmatically-without-entering-a-text

Answer (score -1):

An easy way to do is the TextChanged Event Of TextBox 1.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text;
    }
```