# C# I'm trying to make autoComplete show even if nothing is typed in the textbox

Tags: c#, autocomplete, textbox

I searched overflow and knew how to make autocomplete work for my textbox but the basic function works when at least one character is typed on my textbox.

I'm trying to show my list when keyCode.down is pressed(even if nothing is typed).

Is there anyway I can access to autocomplete dropdown list?

extra question, I tried to find the definition of AutoCompleteMode only to find
{public enum AutoCompleteMode
None =0, Suggest = 1, Append =2, SuggestAppend = 3}

I wanted to know the actual code of SuggestAppend, Are there anyway to lookup to this actual definition?

Comment: Why don't you use a autocomplete `comboBox` for this? [This will point you in the right direction.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11780558/c-sharp-winforms-combobox-dynamic-autocomplete)

Comment: Doesn't seem easy..See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185587/how-to-make-autocomplete-on-a-textbox-show-suggestions-when-empty) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20920492/how-to-show-autocomplete-programmatically-without-entering-a-text)

Comment: I solved the problem with comboBox, thank you!