# Call TextBox dropdown list on button click

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete, textbox

*Hey guys,*

I have a `TextBox` with `StringCollection` as `AutoCompleteSource`. When user starts typing it filters data by letter etc. as usual. Here is the picture of my `TextBox`:

[image]

As you can see it has "..." custom button in it. Is there any way I can call `DropDown` list with full data from my `StringCollection` inside button click event? I really have no idea how to call `DropDown` list manually.

Comment: Do you want to  load the combo  box by  clicking the button?

Comment: No.. this is TextBox with DropDown list, but the lists source is filtered by users input. I want to show the unfiltered source on button click in the same DropDown list in which filtered results are shown. So, I want to display full data in textbox dropdown without it being filtered.

Comment: It's a buil in dropdown list that opens when autocomplete option is enabled or it is custom drop down list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there no way to access autocomplete box, from your code, see similar question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185587/how-to-make-autocomplete-on-a-textbox-show-suggestions-when-empty)

My suggestion is to put any list control (listbox, for example) below the textbox, set it's data source and set it as unvisible. On your button press, show it!

Comment: I have a lot of textboxes like this one, hiding listbox for all of them would be messy. I think I'll create and place listbox programatically under the parent control of button that triggered event.

Answer (score 0):

```
can you write  the  code for unfiltered source inside the button click event?
then get a DataTable and load Filtered source to  it first.
then load the unfiltered source also to the DataTable. 
finally you can bind the DataTable to the DropDownList using  DropDownList1.DataBind(); method.
```

Comment: Yes, WinForm has Combo Boxes.

Comment: Yeah, but filling combobox with all the data I have takes too long.. Filtered textbox does it better in my case, but I want user to have an option to wait until dropdown is filled on button click as his own choice, but thanks :)