# How to show all data when datagridview textbox is blank using autocomplete? VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I just learned how to use autocomplete in datagridview. All is working except one thing. What I want to happen is when my textbox in datagridview is blank or " " then all of the data inside **Additems(DataCollection)**  should show. Is that possible?

here is a sample code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        DataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3
        DataGridView1.Columns(0).Name = "Product ID"
        DataGridView1.Columns(1).Name = "Product Name"
        DataGridView1.Columns(2).Name = "Product Price"

        Dim row As String() = New String() {"1", "Product 1", "1000"}
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
        row = New String() {"2", "Product 2", "2000"}
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
        row = New String() {"3", "Product 3", "3000"}
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
        row = New String() {"4", "Product 4", "4000"}
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
        Dim titleText As String = DataGridView1.Columns(1).HeaderText
        If titleText.Equals("Product Name") Then
            Dim autoText As TextBox = TryCast(e.Control, TextBox)
            If autoText IsNot Nothing Then
                autoText.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
                autoText.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
                Dim DataCollection As New AutoCompleteStringCollection()
                addItems(DataCollection)
                autoText.AutoCompleteCustomSource = DataCollection
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub addItems(ByVal col As AutoCompleteStringCollection)
        col.Add("Product 1")
        col.Add("Product 2")
        col.Add("Product 3")
        col.Add("Product 4")
        col.Add("Product 5")
        col.Add("Product 6")
        col.Add("item 1")
        col.Add("item 2")
        col.Add("item 3")
    End Sub

End Class
```

here is a sample of what happens:

[image]

Comment: try using `sendkeys`,send any key so that it will suggest results from autocomplete source.

Comment: @akhilkumar where should I put `sendkeys`?

Comment: you want to show autocomplete when you get focus to the column right?

Comment: yes. Autocomplete is working fine as long as i typed something. e.g i typed 's' then all words starting with letter s will show up. What I want to happen is when I did not typed anything or my textfield is blank.

Comment: that means when u click in the columns or on load itself?

Comment: i added a picture so you can imagine what I am doing. I want my program to suggest all of the data when my text is blank or ""

Comment: @Chad Patrick it can be done. When I get booted up I will post a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually There is no such possibility in .net api. Even more there is no such possibility in `IAutoComplete` shell interface which .net is using internally.

So Its better to Use Combobox Dropdowns Or else You should create your own custom Autocomplete control.

even after reading this you are sticking to the same requirement,please visit [Custom AutoComplete Trigger](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16942/AutoComplete-TextBox).

Refer This too.[autocomplete on a TextBox show suggestions when empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185587/how-to-make-autocomplete-on-a-textbox-show-suggestions-when-empty)