# Cause Textbox Autocomplete Suggestions To Appear From Code

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

In a .net WinForm, how do you programatically cause the list of autocomplete suggestions to appear for a textbox?

The code creating the autocomplete source is this

```
inputbox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
inputbox.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange({"foo", "bar"})
inputbox.DisplayAutoCompleteList() '<-pseudo code
```

The code works fine for when the user is typing. but I want to be able to display the autocomplete list at the moment after the list is added.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185587/how-to-make-autocomplete-on-a-textbox-show-suggestions-when-empty I don't believe this behaviour is possible with the standard .NET textbox auto complete functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to override the base functionality of the autocomplete. It is supposed to make suggestions based in user input.

Be that as it may, I stumbled upon this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fa1d73fc-bdee-48d8-9abd-a28591c307cf/display-autocomplete-list-when-textbox-gets-focus?forum=csharpgeneral

```
   [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSetCharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]  
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);  
    private const int CB_SHOWDROPDOWN = 0x014F;  

    private void comboBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {  
        SendMessage(comboBox1.Handle, CB_SHOWDROPDOWN, (IntPtr)1, (IntPtr)0);  
    }
```

I would really suggest making your own flavour, using a combo box.

Comment: What ComboBox are you *Entering*? This is like: `[ComboBox].DroppedDown = true;`. If you have a ComboBox.